# Strange error coming from ActiveRecord (probably)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My development environment:

- Ubuntu 9
- Ruby 1.9.1/1.8.7 (rvm)
- Rails 2.3.5
- Mysql 5.0
- Apache Passenger

Below is the part of the program flow to represent the issue.

Request comes:

```
#action
def create
  begin
    @report = Report.new(params[:report])
    ...  
  rescue LocationNotFound => e
    ...
  end
end
```

Report constructor:

```
class Report
  attr_accessor :locations

  def initialize(params = {})
    @locations = params[:locations] ? fetch_locations(params[:locations]) : []
  end
  ...
end
```

fetch_locations:

```
def fetch_locations(loc_names)
  Rails.logger.debug "LOC_NAMES: " + loc_names.inspect
  ls = Location.find(:all, :conditions => [ # line 57
    "locations.name in (#{loc_names.map{'?'}.join(',')})",
    *loc_names
  ], :include => [:sample_summaries, :samples]) # loc_names will never be empty
  ...
end
```

Location model:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sample_summaries
  has_many :samples, :through => :sample_summaries
  ...
end
```

Now, the first time (after passenger restart) this runs fine and does the job. Most of the consequent times I get the error:

```
Mar-11 11:01:00 #15098 DEBUG: LOC_NAMES: ["Moscow, RF", "London, UK"]
Mar-11 11:01:00 #15098 DEBUG:   Location Load (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `locations` WHERE (locations.name in ('Moscow, RF','London, UK'))
Mar-11 11:01:00 #15098 DEBUG:   SampleSummary Load (0.0ms)   SELECT `sample_summaries`.* FROM `sample_summaries` WHERE (`sample_summaries`.location_id IN (1,3))
Mar-11 11:01:00 #15098 DEBUG:   SampleSummary Columns (0.0ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `sample_summaries`
Mar-11 11:01:00 #15098 FATAL:
NoMethodError (You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.include?):
  app/models/report.rb:57:in `fetch_locations'
  app/models/report.rb:9:in `initialize'
  app/controllers/report_controller.rb:11:in `new'
  app/controllers/report_controller.rb:11:in `create'
```

Looks quite random to me. Any ideas?

P.S. I also tried to wrap the query in `uncached` block, but that didn't change anything.

**EDIT**

Here is what SampleSummary model looks like:

```
class SampleSummary < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :samples
  belongs_to :location
  ... #validations

  default_scope :include => :samples, :order => 'rss_ts desc'
  ...
end
```

**EDIT2**

It doesn't fail in console.

Comment: params[:report] might be nil, an the error comes when calling nil[:locations] in Report#initialize

Comment: That `logger.debug ...` part is there exclusively to show that parameters are coming as they should. And they are, as you can see from the log

Comment: Can you post your sample_summaries model as well?

Comment: just one doubt: why using `["locations.name in (#{loc_names.map{'?'}.join(',')})", *loc_names]` instead of `["locations.name in (?)", loc_names]`?

Comment: Solely because I didn't know there was such a shortcut. So thanks! However, that long code is still correct. Using your version didn't fix the issue.

Comment: yes, i know this wasn't the problem. i was just curious ;]

Comment: what exactly do you have on line 57 of your report model?

Comment: Edited question to reflect where line 57 is `ls = Location.find(:all, :conditions => [ # line 57`

Comment: You can kinda see it from the log. It starts making queries associated with `find`, but falls down along the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what it is happening:

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/1339-arbase-should-not-be-nuking-its-children-just-because-it-lost-interest

The good news is, it only happens in development mode (where `config.cache_classes = false`). Changing it to `true` will make it go away (at the cost of not forgetting to restart server after each change).

Answer (score 0):

So, if you run this via ./script/console (the relevant part of the controller action) multiple times with the same arguments it randomly fails?  Or it consistently fails?  It's not clear.

Just randomly, why not try...

ls = Location.find(:all, 
    :conditions => ["locations.name in (?)", loc_names], 
    :include => :sample_summaries => {:samples})

Comment: using `:include => {:sample_summaries => :samples}` did not change anything

Answer (score 0):

Since the default scope of sample_summaries includes samples, can you try:

```
def fetch_locations(loc_names)
  ls = Location.find(:all, 
    :conditions => {:locations => {:name => loc_names}, 
    :include => :sample_summaries
  )
end
```

Also, does it fail if you leave the :include off completely?

Comment: Offtopic, does `:conditions => {:locations => {:name => loc_names}` escape loc_names ?

Comment: Good point about stripping out samples from include. Didn't help though

Comment: Leaving :include off completely moves error to another place (where the data - now missing without :include - is supposed to be accessed)

Comment: Yes, anytime you use the hash form of conditions, it will be escaped. 

On a side note, the fact that it's failing without the :include seems to indicate a bigger issue. :include is used for eager loading, reducing DB query load. The fact that you are getting an error without it does not seem right. You mentioned that it works when you first start the server, but subsequent calls gave you the error. Does this still happen without the include or does that always fail?

Comment: It breaks in the same manner (first time ok, others - fail). Thanks for the escaping hint.